# Using NFC with Flutter on a psychical device Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, nfc

I'm trying to make NFC work on a **iOS** phone and now I'm getting this error:

```
[CoreNFC] 00000002 82426be0 -[NFCHardwareManager areFeaturesSupported:outError:]:154  XPC Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc was invalidated from this process.}
```

The package I'm currently using is `nfc_manager`

Here is the code that's being used:

```
openNFC() async {
  // Check availability
  bool isAvailable = await NfcManager.instance.isAvailable();
  // Start Session
  if (isAvailable == true) {
    NfcManager.instance.startSession(
      onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
        print(tag);
      },
    );
  } else {
    print("Your device is not compatible with NFC");
  }
  // Stop Session
  NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
}
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance❤️